# How did Valkyrie get a pegasus in "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

We didn't see any pegasus with Valkyrie in *Thor: Ragnarok*, and it seemed like Hela had killed them all earlier.

And as Doctor Strange brought people from the same timeline, how did she get the pegasus back?

Comment: Presumably the Banner snap sucked all the missing Asgardians to Norway, and didn't make them reappear in empty space where their ship had once been...  maybe it did the same for their mounts that had been on the ship...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Not all the Pegasi were killed during the battle with Hela

If you look carefully you can see many Pegasi escaping the battle in the upper middle of the screen.

[image: Pegasi escaping in the background]

Presumably, Valkyrie knew where they were or perhaps they were taken during the evacuation of Asgard and then escaped the *Statesman* before Thanos attacked (just like the inhabitants of New Asgard).